# Bind 9 process of named is using one core cpu only

Tags: linux, cpu, bind, multithreading

i Have a DNS server running on Debian os , the named process is taking 394% of cpu.

i noticed it is using one core of the 1 cores provided to the whole VM .

```
top - 17:29:04 up 105 days,  1:33,  1 user,  load average: 3.54, 3.48, 3.64
Tasks: 236 total,   2 running, 234 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 14.9 us,  9.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 74.2 id,  0.3 wa,  0.0 hi,  1.6 si,  0.0 st

KiB Mem : 12286032 total,   192324 free,  1279560 used, 10814148 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  6291452 total,  6222940 free,    68512 used. 10488136 avail Mem

PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
72010 bind      20   0 1767108 1.057g   6432 S 394.0  9.0 138481:39 named
1187 syslog    20   0  260624   2832   1244 S  20.9  0.0  20317:00 rsyslogd
507 root      20   0   43872   8472   6040 R  18.2  0.1  19587:07 systemd-journal
```

is there any method to load balance the load of this process across multi-core ?

Edit 1 : [adding top + 1 to show all 16 Cores Usage ]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If it's using one core, it can't also be using over 100%. Try the 'top' command, and press the '1' key to see all cores.

Comment: i added a picture above showing the output of top + 1